# Notepad shortcut issue with %WINDIR% is not defined

Tags: windows-7

After an environment variable Path contains more than 2047 characters, my laptop creates an issue with Notepad shortcut, like icon is gone and after click on shortcut it pop-up msg

> %WINDIR% is not defined

Is there are ways of fixing this issue other than truncating environment variable Path to be less than 2048 characters?

Answer (score 2):

Create a *new* environment variable for commonly used sub-paths, similar to WINDIR and SystemRoot. For example, if **C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\** is part of two or more locations in PATH, create the variable **INTEL64 = C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\**.

Then, just as %WINDIR% substitutes for the path to the Windows folder, you would substitute **%INTEL64%\DAL** for **C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL**, a *lot* shorter.

Two notes on editing PATH:

1. **Back up** the original, as a mistake can cause serious issues.
2. The easiest way to edit PATH, I find, is to use *Notepad++* to replace all the semicolons [;] with carriage-return-line-feeds [\r\n], make the edits, and then replace the semicolons back for the CRLF. The CRLF format is *much* more readable.